# Using Simple language in Camel log

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have some problems with logging in Camel. I have a log statement like this:

```
from(jmsOutboundInEndpoint).routeId("outbound")
    .to(generateLogEndpoint("outbound.in"))     
    .process(endpointProcessor)
    .to(generateLogEndpoint("outbound.endpoint.set"))
    .to(DIRECT_REQUEST_OUTBOUND)
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Message body: ${body}");
```

And in the log file I can see the `Message body: ${body}` instead of actual body of the message. What am I doing wrong? I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/log.html

Comment: Change the code to use `simple("Message body: ${body}")`

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

`log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Message body: ${body}")` should work properly. Please, insert the log statement directly after the `from` statement and verify if the log is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you need a `multicast()` to make multiple `.to()`

```
from(jmsOutboundInEndpoint).routeId("outbound")
.multicast()
 // output 1
.to(generateLogEndpoint("outbound.in"))     
 // output 2
.process(endpointProcessor)
.to(generateLogEndpoint("outbound.endpoint.set"))
 //output 3, does not include changes by endpointProcessor
.to(DIRECT_REQUEST_OUTBOUND)
// output 4
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Message body: ${body}")
// this multicast case is dangling route end, it will auto-stop
.end();  // end multicast
```